# Stacking multiple UIViewControllers and presenting the last one in UINavigationController stack

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5, uistoryboard

Possibly simple request here but I can't find the solution and it is bugging me for days.

I'm building simple options page where users could jump to desired page and I'm using `UINavigationController` instance to manage hierarchy. My `storyboard` looks like this:

[image]

Viewcontrollers are connected with `push segues` fired on next button, while I use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` for previous button. If I connect, for instance, button labeled  `2` on 5VC with 2VC through push segue, I get to the second page, but if I want to use previous button I will land to options page or 5VC which is something I don't want. Instead, I would like to be able to use previous button to go to first page, while on second page.

The way I see it, if I am on third page (3VC) and I call options page (5VC) and select button 3, system should stack 1VC-2VC and present 3VC, so I would be able to go to 2VC through `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` request.

I think the solution is somehow connected with `setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated`, but I don't know the syntax how to make things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 cases

### Back to one of ancestors in the middle with push

case 5VC=>2VC, 5VC=>3VC:

```
NSArray *vcs = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
for(NSInteger i = vcs.count - 2; i > 0; i--) {

    // find the target and its parent view controller
    // i.e. class of 2VC is ViewController2
    if([vcs[i] isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]) {
        UIViewController *target = vcs[i];
        UIViewController *parent = vcs[i - 1];

        // pop to its parent view controller with NO animation
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:parent animated:NO];

        // push the target from its parent
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:target animated:YES];

        return;
    }
}
```

### Back to the root view controller with push

case 5VC=>1VC:

```
UIViewController *root = self.navigationController.viewControllers.firstObject;

// reset view controllers stack with self as root. 
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[self] animated:NO];

// push target from self
[self.navigationController pushViewController:root animated:YES];

// reset navigation stack with target as root.
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[root] animated:NO];
```

### Push new VC from one of ancestors

case 5VC=>4VC

```
NSArray *vcs = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
for(NSInteger i = vcs.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    // find the parent view controller
    if([vcs[i] isKindOfClass:[ViewController3 class]]) {
        UIViewController *parent = vcs[i];

        // pop to the parent with NO animation 
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:parent animated:NO];

        // perform segue from the parent
        [parent performSegueWithIdentifier:@"push4VC" sender:self];
        return;
    }
}
```

On the particular your case(5VC=>4VC), you know 3VC is the self's parent, you can get the parent directly:

```
NSArray *vcs = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UIViewController *parent = vcs[vcs.count - 2]; // [vcs.count-1] is self.
[self.navigationController popToViewController:parent animated:NO];
[parent performSegueWithIdentifier:@"push4VC" sender:self];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me please how the code would look like if I were to use modal segue instead of push to go from 3VC to options (5VC) and most importantly back. Basically, I have trouble to implement dismiss modal view first (dismiss modal 5VC) and then pop back to some viewcontroller... Let's say, 3VC. I appreciate your help.